# Resolving hours and minutes from total minutes in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, casting

I'm trying to get hours and minutes from a total minute count. I got this bit of code from another website, but the first part doesn't seem to work:

```
cast(TimeToAdd/60 as varchar) + ' hours ' +
cast(TimeToAdd%60 as varchar) + ' minutes' as [Converted]
```

With TimeToAdd worth 75 minutes, the answer should be 1 hour 15 minutes, but all I am getting is 0 hour 15 minutes.

Here is the full SQL:

```
select pu.ProjectID, c.ClientName, p.ProjectTitle, sum(TimeToAdd) as TotalTime, 
cast(TimeToAdd/60 as varchar) + ' hours ' +
cast(TimeToAdd%60 as varchar) + ' minutes' as [Converted]
from dbo.ProjectUsers pu
left join dbo.Projects p
on pu.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
left join dbo.ProjectTime pt
on p.ProjectID = pt.ProjectID
inner join dbo.Clients c
on p.ClientID = c.ClientID
where pu.StaffID = 3
group by pu.ProjectID, c.ClientName, p.ProjectTitle, pt.TimeToAdd
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What output you get using this code: `select cast(75/60 as varchar) + ' hours ' + cast(75%60 as varchar) + ' minutes' as [Converted]`?

Comment: You contradict yourself.

Comment: Grrr it's TotalTime we should be doing the conversion on, but this is a dynamically created field, any ideas?

Comment: Use SUM(TimeToAdd) instead of TimeToAdd in your equation. Then you can also remove that from the `GROUP BY` since I'm guessing that doesn't actually make sense for your problem.

Comment: That did it Tom - put it as an answer and I will accept, thanks.

Comment: I think floor() is necesary also

Comment: floor is not nessasary unless TimeToAdd is a decimal or a float.

Comment: if TimeToAdd is INT he must use floor and divide by 60.0 (with the dot) please repeat @Cortright example and for period of 105 minutes will obtain 2 hours 45 minutes. I asumed float I will add .0 to my anwser

Comment: but why would you divide with 60.0 when you want the whole hour ? The second part of the statement takes care of the minute part

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: because 105/60 results 2 that is wrong!!!! and 105/60.0 results 1.75 and floor(105/60.0) results 1 that it the correct value (plus 45 minutes from the other part of the calculation) @Gogster you were adviced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subselect, so you can reference the SUMmed column by name:

```
select
  *,
  cast(TotalTime/60 as varchar) + ' hours ' +
  cast(TotalTime%60 as varchar) + ' minutes' as [Converted]
from (
  select
    pu.ProjectID,
    c.ClientName,
    p.ProjectTitle,
    sum(TimeToAdd) as TotalTime
  from dbo.ProjectUsers pu
    left join dbo.Projects p on pu.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
    left join dbo.ProjectTime pt on p.ProjectID = pt.ProjectID
    inner join dbo.Clients c on p.ClientID = c.ClientID
  where pu.StaffID = 3
  group by
    pu.ProjectID,
    c.ClientName,
    p.ProjectTitle
) s
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, as below:

```
DECLARE @TimeToAdd INT

SET @TimeToAdd = 75

DECLARE @Hours nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @Minutes nvarchar(50)

SELECT @Hours = CAST(@TimeToAdd/60 as nvarchar) + ' hours'
SELECT @Minutes = CAST(@TimeToAdd%60 as nvarchar) + ' minutes'

PRINT @Hours
PRINT @Minutes
```

Output:

```
1 hours
15 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select pu.ProjectID, c.ClientName, p.ProjectTitle, sum(TimeToAdd) as TotalTime, 
cast(FLOOR(sum(TimeToAdd)/60.0) as varchar) + ' hours ' +
cast(sum(TimeToAdd)%60 as varchar) + ' minutes' as [Converted]
from dbo.ProjectUsers pu
left join dbo.Projects p
on pu.ProjectID = p.ProjectID
left join dbo.ProjectTime pt
on p.ProjectID = pt.ProjectID
inner join dbo.Clients c
on p.ClientID = c.ClientID
where pu.StaffID = 3
group by pu.ProjectID, c.ClientName, p.ProjectTitle // please remove (I guess), pt.TimeToAdd
```